# Getting 401 Error while fetching list from API after implementing JWT access token in Angular

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, jwt

In my service .ts file i coded like this

```
getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    let httpOptions = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 
    this.securityService.securityObject.bearerToken);
    return this.http.get(environment.baseApiUrl + "user", { headers: httpOptions });
}
```

In the bearerToken we have token value, but the **headers** showing in the **httpOptions** is like below image. (took from the console)

[image]

in my controller class i have

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
```

In my HttpInterceptor i have written like

```
  var token = localStorage.getItem("bearerToken");

  if (token) {
  const newReq = request.clone(
    {
      headers: request.headers
        .set('Authorization',
          'Bearer ' + token)
    });

  return next.handle(newReq);
}
else {
  return next.handle(request);
}
```

my local storage have my  token value, but

When i debug the code what i can see is its not entering inside the **clone**  is this is the reason for headers not any entries like my image. Is clone ok to use there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These were the main culprits which caused my issue

1. Like corsaro mentioned interceptors will take care our http request no need to mention it separately
2. In my **startup.cs** file i was using before like this

   ```
   app.UseAuthorization();
   app.UseAuthentication();
   ```

I swapped it's order to

```
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseAuthorization();
```

3. In my interceptor class i modified header section to this

   ```
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token
      })
   ```
4. Copied JwtSettings which declared in the appsettings.json file to appsettings.development.json file for local debug

Now after making these changes its working fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

i m use on the same way, i don't think it s this the problem, but i think you don't need to set also when you call the get user

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

    token:string;

    intercept(req, next) {
        const authService = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);

        this.token = authService.getToken();

        const authRequest = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token) 
        });

        return next.handle(authRequest);
    }
}
```

if you look on the tools network it s already set from Interceptor
Only:

```
getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(environment.baseApiUrl + "user")
}
```

Comment: This one make sense. But even after making the changes i am still gets 401. One thing i noticed is when i remove the authorize attribute from my controller i am able to hit my method

Comment: Thanks corsaro for your input, i figured out the issue and posted as answer :)